# How to unregister middleware in Telegraf?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf.js

When I add `bot.hears(...)`, it registers middleware for handling matching text messages. But now it will handle those messages even if they are sent any time, even if not expected.
So if I am creating a stateful service, I would like to listen to particular messages only at appropriate time.

How can I unregister middleware, so that it does not `hear` any more previously handled messages?

Answer (score 0):

I turned out I was looking for [Scenes](https://telegraf.js.org/modules/scenes.html). How to use them is described on [Github](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/705#issuecomment-549056045).

I'll just post a slightly modified code from the links above:

```
const { Telegraf, Scenes, session } = require('telegraf')

const contactDataWizard = new Scenes.WizardScene(
    'CONTACT_DATA_WIZARD_SCENE_ID', // first argument is Scene_ID, same as for BaseScene
    (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply('Please enter guest\'s first name', Markup.removeKeyboard());
        ctx.wizard.state.contactData = {};
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
    (ctx) => {
        // validation example
        if (ctx.message.text.length < 2) {
            ctx.reply('Please enter real name');
            return;
        }
        ctx.wizard.state.contactData.firstName = ctx.message.text;
        ctx.reply('And last name...');
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
);

const stage = new Scenes.Stage();
stage.register(contactDataWizard);

bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());
```

But I still don't know how to generally implement it, so I need to find it out in the Scenes code of Telegraf.